# ImportError at / No module named 'wsgi' in django

Tags: python, django, openshift

Well, as the title says I'm constantly getting the above error when trying to import a class from another app.

My file structure looks like this (I am on openshift btw):

```
- openshiftappname
    - .openshift
    - data
    - libs
    - wsgi
        - myproject
            - myproject
            - app1
                models.py (file with class to import)
            - app2
                forms.py (file with import)
            manage.py
        - static
        __init__.py
        application
    setup.py
```

My import looks like this:

```
from wsgi.myproject.app1.models import PrivateClient
```

I've also tried:

```
from ..app1.models import PrivateClient
from ..app1 import PrivateClient
```

but both these statements give me the error:
"ValueError at /
attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

contents of wsgi/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

# GETTING-STARTED: change 'myproject' to your project name:
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Note that both apps are added to the installed_apps in the settings file

What should I do? I have no clue why I'm getting this error and I was unable to find a solution on the web after extensive searching. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what that `wsgi` folder is for. Why don't you just import from `myproject.app1...`? In any case, assuming this is in production, can you post your wsgi.py file?

Comment: Make sure you know what python thinks is your current working directory then make your import path from there.

Comment: Assuming you mean the content of the wsgi.py in the myproject folder, I will post its contents :) And when I try to import from myproject... I just get an unresolved reference error...

Comment: I think @DanielRoseman mean is to import as `from app1.models import PrivateClient`

Answer (score 0):

Just use what @ahmed-hosny mentioned in comments:
`from app1.models import PrivateClient`
Please always reply to comments, answer your question (if nobody else did) and mark it as answered. Thanks.